# (c)make - resursive compile

Tags: c++, recursion, makefile, compilation, cmake

Let's assume I have directories like:

```
dir1
    main.cpp
    dir2
        abc.cpp
    dir3
        def.cpp
        dir4
            ghi.cpp
            jkl.cpp
```

And let's assume that main.cpp includes dir2/abc.cpp and dir3/def.cpp, def.cpp includes dir4/ghi.cpp and dir4/jkl.cpp.

My question is, how can I have **one** Makefile/CMakeLists.txt in dir1/ which goes in each directory recursively and compiles *.cpp, and then "joins" them?

Sorry for my english, hope that I explained my question well!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that main.cpp does '#include dir2/abc.cpp'?  If so, then stop doing that.

Comment: No, I'm doing #include "dir2/abc.h", which of course exists, but I didn't think that's important in this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For makefile, dir1/Makefile should:

- declare that main.o dependends on dir2/abc.o and dir3/def.o
- declare how to create dir2/abc.o and dir3/def.o

As for cmake it detects such dependencies "automatically" (binary depended on dir2/abc.o and dir3/def.o), so virually you don't need care about it.

Comment: I was thinking without specifying what are dependicies, so cmake is my choice... But, I was searching on the internet, before asking this question, about how to make this ( since I'm totally new in cmake ), but could find anything... Could you help me, please ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation of not very good, not enough examples. I advise you just to try to make small demo to investigate it. From my experience I know for example, that when I come to compile directory creating executable, cmake compiles first other directories containing libraries the binary should compile first

Answer (score 1):

One CMakeLists.txt file:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE MAIN_SOURCES "dir1/*.cpp")

add_executable(MainExecutable ${MAIN_SOURCES})
# or
add_library(MyLibrary ${MAIN_SOURCES})
```

I am unsure what you mean by "joining" the sources.  I am assuming here that you are combining them into either a library or an executable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open argument whether recursive make is a good thing. Please see [this blog entry](http://bradapp.blogspot.com/2007/02/recursive-make-reconsidered.html) for a survey of relatively up-to-date pro and con papers.

Comment: I need this because I'm making projects where users should be able to add their codes, and I want to avoid editing Makefile...